# Pyspark, PandasUDF; How to return a matrix using Pyspark.PandasUDF?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to implement a pandasUDF function in Pyspark which returns a matrix of float numbers. I have tried, but the bellow appeared.

```
RuntimeError: ('Exception thrown when converting pandas.Series (float64) to 
Arrow Array (list<item: float>). It can be caused by overflows or other
unsafe conversions warned by Arrow. Arrow safe type check can be disabled by
using SQL config `spark.sql.execution.pandas.convertToArrowArraySafely`.',
ArrowNotImplementedError("NumPyConverter doesn't implement <list<item: float>>
conversion. ",))
```

I wonder if you have an idea to get a spark-data-frame as the below table.

Desired output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  P0|                  P1|                  P2|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|-6.384              |-2.950              |-2.095              |
|-4.102              |-7.101              |-8.184              |
|-1.614              |4.4842              |-10.00              |
|-6.166              |-3.186              |-2.076              |
.
.
.
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

First:

Converting the output into `StringType` as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter as Cs
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

structList = []
for i in range(k):
    structList.append(StructField('P' + str(i),
            ArrayType(StringType()),
            True))
schema = StructType(structList) 

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def apply_Func(data):
    data = pd.DataFrame(data.astype(float).values[:,:-1])
    label = someFunc(data.values,k,IR,i)
    data['labels'] = label
    leader = []
    f = list(Cs(label))
    f.sort()
    for ii in f:
        leader.append([round(np.mean(z), 10) for z in data[data['labels']==ii].\
               values[:, :-1].T])
    cols = ['P'+str(i) for i in range(k)]
    leader = pd.DataFrame(leader, columns=cols)
    for c in cols:
        leader[c] = leader[c].map(str)
    return leader

df2.groupby('chunks').apply(apply_Func).show()
```

The output is as follows which in each element I have the character list of the float numbers.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  P0|                  P1|                  P2|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[-, 6, ., 3, 8, 4...|[-, 2, ., 9, 5, 0...|[-, 2, ., 0, 9, 5...|
|[-, 4, ., 1, 0, 2...|[-, 7, ., 1, 0, 1...|[-, 8, ., 1, 8, 4...|
|[-, 1, ., 6, 1, 4...|[4, ., 4, 8, 4, 2...|[-, 1, 0, ., 0, 0...|
|[-, 6, ., 1, 6, 6...|[-, 3, ., 1, 8, 6...|[-, 2, ., 0, 7, 6...|
|[-, 3, ., 9, 4, 2...|[-, 7, ., 1, 3, 8...|[-, 8, ., 1, 8, 7...|
|[-, 1, ., 6, 4, 4...|[4, ., 4, 9, 9, 3...|[-, 9, ., 7, 3, 0...|
|[-, 3, ., 7, 5, 5...|[-, 7, ., 0, 0, 7...|[-, 8, ., 3, 4, 3...|
|[-, 6, ., 1, 0, 8...|[-, 3, ., 1, 7, 2...|[-, 2, ., 0, 4, 6...|
|[-, 1, ., 9, 2, 4...|[4, ., 4, 2, 4, 9...|[-, 9, ., 9, 3, 2...|
|[-, 4, ., 1, 1, 0...|[0, ., 5, 0, 0, 5...|[-, 5, ., 9, 3, 1...|
|[-, 3, ., 7, 5, 5...|[-, 7, ., 2, 2, 4...|[-, 8, ., 1, 2, 7...|
|[-, 0, ., 1, 9, 8...|[3, ., 8, 5, 3, 9...|[-, 1, 1, ., 1, 2...|
|[-, 1, ., 6, 6, 1...|[4, ., 6, 5, 1, 5...|[-, 9, ., 9, 0, 6...|
|[-, 3, ., 9, 0, 1...|[-, 7, ., 2, 4, 6...|[-, 8, ., 0, 6, 3...|
|[-, 6, ., 1, 3, 7...|[-, 2, ., 9, 7, 3...|[-, 1, ., 9, 7, 3...|
|[-, 6, ., 5, 5, 1...|[-, 2, ., 9, 5, 6...|[-, 2, ., 1, 7, 2...|
|[-, 1, ., 5, 2, 9...|[4, ., 5, 2, 0, 9...|[-, 9, ., 9, 5, 9...|
|[-, 4, ., 0, 2, 9...|[-, 7, ., 0, 5, 7...|[-, 8, ., 0, 9, 4...|
|[-, 6, ., 5, 8, 1...|[-, 3, ., 0, 4, 0...|[-, 2, ., 1, 5, 4...|
|[-, 3, ., 9, 4, 1...|[-, 6, ., 9, 6, 3...|[-, 8, ., 2, 0, 2...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Second phase:

Then turning the output into a normal matrix in the Pyspark:

```
for c in results.columns:
    results = results.withColumn(c, F.array_join(c, ""))
results = results.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in results.columns))
results.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|        P0|        P1|        P2|
+----------+----------+----------+
|-6.3002896|-3.1039708|-2.0802138|
|-3.9664164|-6.9847507| -8.062131|
|-1.8714522|  4.196398|-10.053752|
|-1.4888309| 4.3933063|-10.096599|
|-6.4817667|-3.1598282|-1.9742265|
| -4.044648| -7.144871| -8.267062|
|-1.7549628| 4.5405264| -9.912325|
|-3.8847973|-7.0680466|  -7.91784|
| -6.434804|-3.2674906|-1.9079945|
|-1.7493968| 4.4715776| -9.837081|
|-6.4625697|-3.0429673|-1.9384751|
|-3.9936383|-7.1258874| -8.427638|
|-3.8748856| -7.047747| -8.218606|
|-1.6524452| 4.2945223| -9.954149|
|-6.3087454|-3.1643403|-1.9838226|
| -5.355266|-5.0064306|-4.5695004|
| -2.995949|-7.3578677| -8.825416|
|-1.6750498|  4.370491| -9.852942|
| -1.511777| 4.3346696| -9.993404|
| -5.128389| -4.756383|-4.7434697|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

```
results
Output:    DataFrame[P0: float, P1: float, P2: float]
```